# Intellij navigate to balloon notification link

Tags: intellij-idea, notifications, navigation, shortcut

How can I navigate to links in balloon notifications like this via the keyboard?

[image: http://screenshooter.net/101973359/fvwlaab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the messages are logged in EventLog.

[image]

Normally it will be in bottom right corner.

There is no Keyboard shortcut assigned by default. But you add a shortcut.

1. Go to `Settings --> Keymap`

   [image]
2. Search for `Event Log` and click edit
3. Select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

   [image]
4. Press the keys you wish to assign, If the selected key stroke is already used you will see a error message so choose a different one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. But how can I accpept something? (I mean with keyboard so dont using pc mouse)  In this example "configure" http://screenshooter.net/101973359/gbjrqfl

Comment: We are every close to resovle problem my friend. I mean when I have event log window http://screenshooter.net/101973359/gtjpopn I like to click at "Configure" without using my mouse http://screenshooter.net/101973359/puasrxc. I like to lern how to navigate without mouse and its going for me pretty well but this problem I think is a big dragon for me. I was trying put the text indicator on "Configure" and press "enter", "space" etc. but this dont work.

Comment: I don't think that possible.